# How can i read string text off both word file or a pdf thats open in a browser

Tags: c#, unit-testing, pdf, ms-word, coded-ui-tests

I'm currently building automation for this web application for my job that have links that opens either a word document, a web page or opens up a pdf document in the browser in the same screen. Now i have to acct for all of these three scenarios.  All i'm trying to do is read the text from the pdf browser, or the word document that opens up and read the related text off these documents.

I know how to read the related text from the web page that opens but for

the other two options i dont really know what i have to do.  I have searched google and have not seen anything relating to this issue.  Currently with the pdf doc that i opened. I have tried reading the text off the msaa Edit control and tried to get text property of it like below

```
var returnPDFdoc =  ReturnPDFDoc();
string myStringPdf = returnPDFdoc.Text;
```

This did not bring back any text from the the screen other then the document relative path on server

When i read these strings out i plan on comparing them and doing an assertion on them.

Can someone point me to the right direction on doing this.

Thnks

Answer (score 1):

In order to "read" a PDF file you'll need to use a PDF library such as [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) and load the document into there using code similar to:

```
    public static string ExtractTextFromPdf(string path)
    {
        using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path))
        {
            StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
            {
                text.Append(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i));
            }

            return text.ToString();
        }
    }
```

In your case, you'd need to load the PDF via its URL.

For the MS Word part you'll need to use the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word assembly to load the doc. See http://www.dotnetperls.com/word for an example. From what I recall, the only issue with using this assembly is that you need to have office installed on the machine that you running your application on.

Comment: Thanks atselevich, I"m going to try to implement this. I'll keep forum updated. Thnks

Answer (score 0):

There's another possible solution - it worked for me in another situation so maybe it will work for you as well.

To read the text content of a pdf file from an acrobat reader open file:

after getting the window parent of the pdf file, i've searched for a control call of type "Document:"

```
UITestControl control = new UITestControl(parentWindow);
control.SearchProperties.Add[UITestControl.PropertyNames.ControlType] = "Document";
```

inside this control there's a WinEdit control whose text property contains the content of the file;

```
 WinEdit pdfEdit= new WinEdit(control);

string Content = pdfEdit.Text;
```

now you can do all your assertions on Content.

Answer (score 0):

Coded UI can access the text in some PDF files by opening then in a program such as Acrobat, doing a select-all then a copy and then read the contents from the clipboard. After opening the file send the characters control-A then control-C (the normal select-all and copy shortcuts).

I believe some PDF files have permissions or properties set in ways that prevent copying of whole documents.